# Advice to Method or MethodHandle

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj

I need to convert an Advice Object from AspectJ to a java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.
I could do that by converting the Advice to a java.lang.reflect.Method and then using java.lang.reflect.MethodHandles.Lookup.unreflect.
But how can I convert an AspectJ Advice to a java.lang.reflect.Method?
Has anyone an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My supervisor had an idea and we solved it with a little hack.

```
Advice adv;
Method m = null;
Field field = AdviceImpl.class.getDeclaredField("adviceMethod");
field.setAccessible(true);
m = (Method) field.get(adv);
```